# HttpOkResult returning encapsulated object response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-web-api, serialization

Hi I have a simple web api that returns the IEnumerable of the following object

```
public interface IProductList 
{
string Id { get; set; }
 string Name { get; set; }
}
```

my web api method

```
 [HttpGet]
 public IHttpActionResult GetProducts()
 {
  IEnumerable<IProductList> productList =  //Do some logic 
  return Ok(productList);
 }
```

My Angular code

```
       $http.get('/api/GetProducts').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
       var response = data;                        
       // Do some post success logic
       }).error(function (data, status, header, config) { //error handling });
```

**The problem:**

the issue is ... everything works.. but instead of getting an array of products directly,  i get something like below pic. the array of products is encapuslated with some weird objects. when i got to `response[0].__interceptors[0]` - i see the actual value.(highlighted in green)  **Any thoughts?**
Update - i see this happening only in my Dev environment. doesnt happen in my local. that is getting crazier.

[image]

Comment: Is this Angularjs (v1) or Angular (v2+)?

Comment: @DeborahK its angular 1.5

Comment: OK, I just edited your angular tag to angularjs for clarity.

Comment: how is productlist initialized? from an linq-query? Is it materialized with .ToList()

Comment: i have a ecommerce api that returns the items from ecommerce .. something like  var productlist = context.getAll<IProductList>(Id);